# Load works once only with include and php

Tags: jquery

I have a problem!

take a look at my code:

```
$( '#myModalEditaFunc' ).on( 'hide.bs.modal', function(e){
       $( ".class_exibir-funcionarios" ).load( 
          location.href + ".class_exibir-funcionarios" );
})
```

The above code refresh the php page included on main page. Everyhtings works fine when I click the button , so the page is refreshed. But it works once only.

After that, when I click the button again, nothing happens and the page is not refreshed by `.class_exibir-funcionarios`.

my code

```
<?php

switch( $_GET[ 'page' ] ){
   case 'home':
   ?>
  <h3 class="text-center">Por favor, selecione uma opção acima.</h3>

    <?php
       break;   
       case 'exibir-funcionarios':
     ?>
     <div class="class_exibir-funcionarios"><?php require_once( 'exibir-funcionarios.php' ); ?></div>
    <?php
      break;
     case 'cadastrar-novo-funcionario':
      require_once( 'cadastro-funcionario.php' );
       break;
     default:
   require_once( '404.php' );
       break;               
  }
// END switch
?>

When I close my modal I call this:
$( '#myModalEditaFunc' ).on( 'hide.bs.modal', function(e){
       $( ".class_exibir-funcionarios" ).load( location.href + " .class_exibir-funcionarios" );
   });
```

So, the div .class_exibir-funcionarios is refreshed and its content as well.    But when I click the button to do the same operation the load does not works.

Help me please

Comment: You need to provide more complete code to find a problem in it. Please, create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)

Comment: Make your code highlighted as a code block so that some can read it without any complexity.

Comment: Is `#myModalEditaFunc` descendant of `.class_exibir-funcionarios`?